# Error installing vagrant-libvirt plugin on OS X

Tags: macos, vagrant, libvirt, vagrant-libvirt

I'm encountering the error below when running `vagrant plugin install vagrant-libvirt`

##### Setup

1. install Homebrew

   ```bash
   /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
   ```
2. install in Homebrew

   ```bash
   brew install --cask vagrant && \
   brew install make gcc qemu libiconv libvirt
   ```
3. double check libvirt path

```
➜  ~ brew --prefix libvirt
/opt/homebrew/opt/libvirt
```

##### Update path

```
HOMEBREW_HOME="/opt/homebrew/opt"
LIBICONV_HOME="$HOMEBREW_HOME/libiconv"

export PATH="$LIBICONV_HOME/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOMEBREW_HOME/make/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
export LDFLAGS="-L$LIBICONV_HOME/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I$LIBICONV_HOME/include"
export CONFIGURE_ARGS="with-libvirt-lib=$(brew --prefix libvirt)/lib with-libvirt-include=$(brew --prefix libvirt)/include"
```

##### Error

```
➜  ~ vagrant plugin install vagrant-libvirt

Installing the 'vagrant-libvirt' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
Fetching formatador-1.1.0.gem
Fetching fog-core-2.3.0.gem
Fetching fog-json-1.2.0.gem
Fetching nokogiri-1.13.9-x86_64-darwin.gem
Fetching fog-xml-0.1.4.gem
Fetching ruby-libvirt-0.8.0.gem
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Vagrant failed to properly resolve required dependencies. These
errors can commonly be caused by misconfigured plugin installations
or transient network issues. The reported error is:

ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/yakforward/.vagrant.d/gems/2.7.6/gems/ruby-libvirt-0.8.0/ext/libvirt
/opt/vagrant/embedded/bin/ruby -I /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r ./siteconf20221111-11883-1v7zec5.rb extconf.rb
Looking for libvirt in /opt/homebrew/opt/libvirt/include and /opt/homebrew/opt/libvirt/lib
checking for virConnectOpen() in -lvirt... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/opt/vagrant/embedded/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-libvirt-include
    --with-libvirt-lib
    --with-virt-dir
    --without-virt-dir
    --with-virt-include
    --without-virt-include=${virt-dir}/include
    --with-virt-lib
    --without-virt-lib=${virt-dir}/lib
    --with-virtlib
    --without-virtlib
extconf.rb:44:in `<main>': No working libvirt installation found (RuntimeError)

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Users/yakforward/.vagrant.d/gems/2.7.6/extensions/x86_64-darwin-19/2.7.0/ruby-libvirt-0.8.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/yakforward/.vagrant.d/gems/2.7.6/gems/ruby-libvirt-0.8.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/yakforward/.vagrant.d/gems/2.7.6/extensions/x86_64-darwin-19/2.7.0/ruby-libvirt-0.8.0/gem_make.out
```

info

```
➜  ~ neofetch
                    'c.          yakforward@yakforward.local
                 ,xNMM.          ---------------------------
               .OMMMMo           OS: macOS 13.0.1 22A400 arm64
               OMMM0,            Host: MacBookAir10,1
     .;loddo:' loolloddol;.      Kernel: 22.1.0
   cKMMMMMMMMMMNWMMMMMMMMMM0:    Uptime: 53 mins
 .KMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWd.    Packages: 89 (brew)
 XMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMX.      Shell: zsh 5.8.1
;MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM:       Resolution: 1440x900
:MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM:       DE: Aqua
.MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMX.      WM: Quartz Compositor
 kMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWd.    WM Theme: Blue (Dark)
 .XMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMk   Terminal: iTerm2
  .XMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMK.   Terminal Font: Monaco 12
    kMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMd     CPU: Apple M1
     ;KMMMMMMMWXXWMMMMMMMk.      GPU: Apple M1
       .cooc,.    .,coo:.        Memory: 1129MiB / 8192MiB
```

```
➜  ~  vagrant --version
Vagrant 2.3.2
```

##### Logs

[mkmf.log](https://github.com/vagrant-libvirt/vagrant-libvirt/files/9991279/mkmf.log)
[gem_make.out.zip](https://github.com/vagrant-libvirt/vagrant-libvirt/files/9991293/gem_make.out.zip)

Comment: `vagrant plugin install vagrant-libvirt`, this worked for me

Comment: question updated

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

`brew install qemu gcc libvirt.`

Step 2:

```sh
echo 'security_driver = "none"' >> /usr/local/etc/libvirt/qemu.conf
echo "dynamic_ownership = 0" >> /usr/local/etc/libvirt/qemu.conf
echo "remember_owner = 0" >> /usr/local/etc/libvirt/qemu.conf
```

If that doesn't work for you, try [this tutorial](https://www.arthurkoziel.com/qemu-ubuntu-20-04/) together with [this one](https://www.arthurkoziel.com/qemu-on-macos-big-sur/).

Comment: I am not sure what the qemu tutorials have to do with not being able to get the vagrant-libvirt plugin to work.  This solution also doesn't solve the actual issue of getting the vagrant-libvirt plugin to work, and the `/usr/local/etc/libvirt` directory does not even exist even though qemu, gcc and libvirt are all successfully installed with homebrew.

Comment: step one matches the steps I followed; step 2 is completely unrelated to the issue (that of course persists)

Comment: In the [github answer](https://github.com/vagrant-libvirt/vagrant-libvirt/issues/1461#issuecomment-1065939684) it suggests to `export CONFIGURE_ARGS` but it doesn't work. Or how do you apply that?